# Show rich:popupPanel on click of rich:tab

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tabpanel, popuppanel

One page contains the rich face tab panel and having 4 tabs. In one of the tab, I have text box and save button . Without saving the data If i move to another tab, It should show the popup saying unsaved data and prevent the navigation.

I tried calling a popup using different java script loading attributes of rich:tabPanel but not serving the purpose.

Here is the code

```
    <rich:tabPanel onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.show();return false"  switchType="ajax"  id="wizardTab" itemChangeListener="#{bean.tabChange}" activeItem="#{bean.activeTab}">
    <rich:tab id="tab1" 
              // tab1

    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab id="tab2" 


    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab id="tab3" 


    </rich:tab>

    <rich:tab id="tab4" 
                        <h:inputText id="test" 
                                     styleClass="span2" maxlength="25"
                                     value="#{bean.rowForChange.code}">
                                     <f:ajax event="blur" execute="@this"/>
                        </h:inputText>
                        <h:commandButton value="Update" styleClass="button"
                                                     style="width:160px"
                                                     action="#{bean.updtae}">
                                        <a4j:ajax execute="paramValue"
                                                  render="table simeditPnl" />
                        </h:commandButton>

    </rich:tab>

</rich:tabPanel>

    <rich:popupPanel render="#{jCRDataRefreshManagement.updateStatus}" id="confirmation" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
           <f:facet name="header">Confirmation</f:facet>
       <h:panelGrid>
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
             <h:graphicImage value="/alert.png" />
         <h:outputText value="You have unsaved changes. Are you sure?" style="FONT-SIZE: large;" />
          </h:panelGrid>
          <h:panelGroup>
             <input type="button" value="OK"
          onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();submit();return false" />
         <input type="button" value="Cancel"
          onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();return false" />
          </h:panelGroup>
       </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

If any unsaved data on the text box on tab 4 and tried to click on any other tab it should stay in the tab 4 and show the  confirmation poupup as above.

With this implementation my popup is opening whenever I am clicking the tab.

Please point out the mistake I am doing or give the suggestion for above scenario.
Any help appretiated

Comment: Please add the code you are using.

Comment: added the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click use `onbeforeitemchange` and return false if you don't want the tabs to switch.

If you want to delay the switching use something like this:

```
saveTabs = function(event) {
    oldItem = event.rf.data.oldItem,
    newItem = event.rf.data.newItem;
}

<rich:tabPanel id="tabPanel" onbeforeitemchange="saveTabs(event); return false;" >
```

And when you decide to switch use:

```
RichFaces.component("form:tabPanel").__itemsSwitcher().exec(oldItem, newItem);
```